# IBM WebSphere MQ Triggering issue

Tags: triggers, ibm-mq

I'm trying to achieve following scenario 
When a new message arrives to queue manager it should automatically trigger my console application. Then it will fetch that message and write the message in to a file. I already completed this part. But I'm having problem with triggering message queue

Here is how I configured my message queue

I created two queues one is called LocalQueue and other one is InitQueue which is SYSTEM.DEFAULT.INITIATION.QUEUE.

[image]

and set "Trigger" properties in my LocalQueue

[image]

Then Created trigger monitor

[image]

In process definition object I set my console application path

[image]

So my problem is, It doesn't work as it expect and I checked my client machine 
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\errors\AMQERR01.LOG and server machine C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\errors log files. I couldn't find anything on them

---

**Update**
Based on Morag answer I changed my process name
[image]

Comment: https://2freeclear.wordpress.com/2014/11/15/invoke-c-console-application-on-new-message-arrival-in-ibm-websphere-mq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the trigger monitor is running and has opened the initiation queue in INPUT(i.e. for GET) mode. Only then queue manager will put a trigger message into initiation queue. Here is what I did to get it working:

I did the setup just like you except for service. I manually started runmqtmc as

```
   SET MQSERVER=<channel name>/TCP/<connname>
   runmqtmc -m <qmname> -q <initq>
```

Put a test message on local queue. That triggered an event and my application started.

Comment: Many thanks, I ran this runmqtmc as you suggested SET MQSERVER=SVRCOMMUNICATION/TCP/192.168.10.2(1436) 
runmqtmc -m TriggerTest -q InitQueue and changed my trigger type to "Every" Now I'm able to write messages in to my file. I would like to know isn't there any other way to set this command on "Start Command" property? I set "Service Type" as "Command" but it always shows Service Status = Stopped

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918309/trigger-monitor-as-an-mq-service-object-how-to-get-status

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have named your `TriggerMonitor` Service object in the queue attribute where you should put the process object name `FetchMessages`.

Comment: Hi Morag Thanks for your response. I changed Process Name to "FetchMessages" and put a new message. But I didn't get that message in to my file. I checked my local and server errors folders . They also don't have any information. So could you please give me some idea to solve this issue. Thank you. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The `Start Args` for your trigger monitor Service object appears to be telling the trigger monitor to monitor the `LocalQueue` and not the `InitQueue`.

Comment: tx and I changed that property as -m TriggerTest -q InitQueue

Comment: ohh yeah Thanks to you and Shashi I managed to get a workable solution but there is a little problem... Currently I'm running trigger monitor from command prompt. Even though I set runmqtmc.exe in  "Start Command" property it is showing me "Service Status" as Stopping. Is there way to make this runmqtmc running as a background service on windows without starting cmd ?

Comment: I thought this warranted a new question or it would get buried in this one and no other person could find it in the future, so I created the question and answerd it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918309/trigger-monitor-as-an-mq-service-object-how-to-get-status/26918348

Comment: I changed the service type to server and started the service but it is still showing me service type = stopped. Please check the image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ujSxOUw0-pODdlbmVrOEh3ZUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Was the other exe still running at the time? I think you can't have two with the same exe in order for it to be able to tell the status.

Comment: btw - why are you using runmqtmc (i.e. the client version) if you are starting it with the queue manager?

Comment: I checked my local and server machines' task managers so there is no runmqtmc.exe or runmqtrm.exe running as background process.

actually our scenario is, we have departments suppose DepartmentA has websphere server and there are other departmentB,C,D...etc.
So other departments connect to Department A's web sphere server as clients. Then they get their messages by their own dedicated channels
We are using server - client model. So once this project goes live I don't have much control over server. For that reason I need to use runmqtmc.exe service within my department.

Comment: The purpose of runmqtmc is to run on a machine that is different from the queue manager. You are running runmqtmc on the same machine as the queue manager. You should either use the local version of the trigger monitor if you are going to run it via a SERVICE object on the same machine as the queue manager, or run it on the client machine (and thus not use the SERVICE object).