# Trigger Monitor as an MQ Service object - how to get status

Tags: triggers, ibm-mq

I have created an MQ Service object to run my Trigger Monitor thus:-

```
DEFINE SERVICE('TriggerMonitor') +
       CONTROL(QMGR) +
       STARTCMD('C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\runmqtrm') +
       STARTARG('-m TriggerTest -q InitQueue')
```

Even though I set runmqtrm.exe in  "Start Command" property it is showing me "Service Status" as Stopping. Is there way to make this runmqtmc running as a background service on windows without having to run it in a command prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see status of a program running as an MQ Service Object, it must be of type `SERVER`. The default is type `COMMAND` which allows you to have as many of the program running, but therefore means you can't display status of it. Define the Service Object with `SERVTYPE(SERVER)` and then `DISPLAY SVSTATUS` will show status of the running program.

Read more about this in [Working with Services](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q020970_.htm)

Also, another helpful hint looking at your `STARTCMD` value, did you know that you can use a replaceable insert instead of having to provide the full installation path to the program. Read more about this in [Replaceable inserts on service definitions](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q021010_.htm)